# Sandvox: Only reachable within local network

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, leopard

I have several Mac Minis using several OS (10.7.2-Intel Core 2 Duo, 10.8.5-Intel Core i5, 10.5.8-Power PC, 10.9.5-Intel Core i5, 10.6.8-Intel Core 2 Duo). I am using serving pages from all and built the sites using Sandvox. Until a couple of weeks ago everything was running fine. Also using DynDNS. Recently i modified some info on several and now Sandvox replies:

Only reachable within local network

Every pertinent port in the router is open… internally the page is webserved…

help!

thank you for your time and knowledge

Comment: So what kind of info did you actually modify? You just withhold the most interesting part of your question...

Comment: Indeed! the bottom line is i don't know… the G4 mini macs have not had updates in a looong time… the intel ones have had regular updates… so i really cant pin point it… some security updates.

Comment: DynDNS changed some parameters… but what does that have to do with the webserver in the mac? (genuine question by the way) its just wierd… thank you for your time

Answer (score -1):

Hello… It was the DynDns software… reinstalled and almost everything is good now… only some bugs now